# Sending Emoji's in push notifications in Parse on iOS

Tags: java, objective-c, json, parse-platform

I'm attempting to get Emoji's to show up in the push notifications sent out by parse, but the only thing I can get to show up in the notification is the utf-8 string (i.e. for police officer, I only see "\ud83d\udc6e").

When I get the message on the device, and decode the string, the Emoji's come back and display just fine.

On my server, I'm using Java, and receive the encoded string, then forward the data onto Parse.  The payload looks like:

```
"data":{"badge":"1","alert":"Crimson: \\ud83d\\udc6e\\ud83d\\ude21\\ud83d\\ude1a"
```

To build the Call to parse, I'm attempting to build a string with

```
data.put("alert", username + ": " + new String(message.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
```

The push notification just shows "\ud83d\udc6e\ud83d\ude21\ud83d\ude1a"

I can only assume I'm doing something wrong with the encoding/decoding of the text string as I'm passing it from iOS to my server, then back to Parse, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

For reference, here is the method I'm using to encode before sending:

```
NSString *uniText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[msg UTF8String]];
NSData *msgData = [uniText dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *encodevalue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:msgData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

And for Decoding when received:

```
NSData *data = [msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *decodevalue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Thanks in advance for any help!